# Is it possible for Spark worker nodes broadcast variables?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a set of large variables that I broadcast. These variables are loaded from a clustered database. Is it possible to distribute the load from the database across worker nodes and then have each one broadcast their specific variables to all nodes for subsequent map operations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the answer it seems is no.

Calling sc.broadcast(someRDD) results in an error. You have to collect() it back to the driver first.

Answer (score 0):

Broadcast variables are generally passed to workers, but I can tell you what I did in a similar case in python.

If you know the total number of rows, you can try to create an RDD of that length and then run a map operation on it (which will be distributed to workers). In the map, the workers are running a function to get some piece of data (not sure how you are going to make them all get different data).

Each worker would retrieve required data through making the calls. You could then do a collectAsMap() to get a dictionary and broadcast that to all workers.

However keep in mind that you need all software dependencies of making client requests on each worker. You also need to keep socket usage in mind. I just did something similar with querying an API and did not see a rise in sockets, although I was making regular HTTP requests. Not sure....

Comment: Its pretty simple to create a partition function for the data coming from the database to guarantee that each worker only gets a unique subset. It seems silly to have one driver process single thread pull all the data from the db just to broadcast the the data onto the cluster. Why not have the cluster do the work?